# $\gamma$ is an inveterible matrix such that $a=b \gamma$, then why is it that we have $\oplus_{i=1}^n Ra_i \subseteq \oplus_{i=1}^n Rb_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, soft-question

Let $a=(a_1,a_2,...a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,...b_n)$ be row vectors with entries in a ring $R$. If $\gamma$ is an invertible matrix such that $a=b \gamma$, then why is it that we have $\oplus_{i=1}^n Ra_i \subseteq \oplus_{i=1}^n Rb_i$

edit: it doesn't need to be a proper subset... Can't find the TeX for that >.<

Comment: Did you mean *invertible*?

Comment: yeah thanks I did mean that

Comment: You said *inveterible* in the title

Comment: Tex is \subseteq

Comment: Is it $R$ commutative? Since $\gamma\in M_n(R)$ and it is invertible, then $R$ has $1$ (obvious remark).